# I upgraded to SP5. The service "ArcGIS Server Object Manager" not start. How to fix this?

Tags: arcgis-server, update

I updated my ArcGIS Server from the SP4 to SP5. On a Windows 7 OS.
But I cannot to start the "ArcGIS SOM" service. An error appears in a popup.

Because of this, the following error occurs in "ArcGIS Server Manager" (the administrator by browser):

"Manager Could not connect to the GIS Server. PLEASE CHECK That the server is online and Functioning properly. Some Manager operations will not be available until the next time you log in to GIS Manager When the server is available."

What can I do to start the "ArcGIS SOM" service?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the error in the popup? Also, are there any errors listed for that service in Events?

Comment: Dear Michael Todd. I translated the message POPUP. When I try to start the service "ArcGIS Server Object Manager" occurs the error below:
"Windows could not start the ArcGIS Server Object Manager service on Local Computer.

Error 1067: The process was started unexpectedly."

Comment: I copied the error that occurs in Windows Service "Argis SOM", see the link: https://sites.google.com/site/sitechristian/erro_log_windows_gis_som.txt

Comment: I runned the ArcGISServerWebApplications10sp5.msp and the  Windows service "ArcGIS SOM" back to run. At the same time, my co-worker change the user service. And it made the service back. But the "ArcGIS Server Manager" (the browser admin) as above. Continue with the same error message. Why?

Comment: On browser the "Arcgis Server Manager" bring this message when I make the login: "Manager could not connect to the GIS Server. Please check that the server is online and functioning properly. Some Manager operations will not be available until the next time you log in to Manager when the GIS server is available."

Comment: Please avoid putting links to screenshots that need to be downloaded as external files.  Make use of the embed image within Stack Exchange so that the files are easy to see and futureproof.  Would also be easier for you to edit your original Q to supplement the additional info.

Comment: Can you also confirm that you have tried my answer below on re-running post installs.

Comment: After I installed SP5 ran just a Post-Install. I'll check it better. I'll try to run the two Post-Install you commented.

Comment: Simon, your answer is right. This fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re run both the GIS and Web post installs is a good place to start after any issues after a post install.  My bets are that that will fix it.

I can edit this answer with more information if you can provide more information about the error your getting when starting the servive into your answer (see Michael Todds comment)

Comment: I should add that my coworker released permissions in the ArcGIS Windows services. I think that may have affected the good result.